# SharePoint Foundation 2013 iFilter for DWG files

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, sharepoint-search, searchserviceapplication, ifilter

We try to use SharePoint SSA to store our DWG files and crawl them. I know that I can simply add the .dwg file extension to the allowed filetypes but we aren't able to search for content inside our .dwg files. Are there any iFilters for .dwg and .dgn Files and how do I install iFilters in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [iFilter Shop](http://www.ifiltershop.com) sells and supports a variety of iFilters. If I recall correctly you will need to perform the installation and registration of the iFilter and then manually ensure that the Foundation SSA correctly registers the iFilter. In Server this is well documented, in Foundation, less so, though the folks at iFilterShop should be able to assist.